# Monit failed to restart apache

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, monit

Apache failed and Monit did not restart it as expected. The error in monit's log is:

```
Error opening Monit id file '/root/.monit.id' for writing-Cannot allocate memory
```

The problem is that Apache went down due to a lack of memory so... is there simply nothing to be done in such a case? The lack of memory killed both the process and the thing monitoring that process.

Anyone know of any strategies for working with such a situation in Monit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually change the default Monit ID file location to something like: `/var/monit/id`

Depending on the version and distribution of your Monit package, the default ID file location can vary. In the current RPMForge package of Monit 5.4, I'm seeing:

```
set idfile /var/monit/id
```

That may help in this case. Some people also try to play tricks to keep Monit running ([like spawning from inittab](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/FAQ#init)), but I really haven't felt the need to do this. Using a more sane ID file location usually resolves my issues.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this (moving that file to a dir in /var). We'll see if it helps.